# Create a list of tuples with consecutive NaN values in all columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to build a list of tuples with the consecutive start and end dates in which all columns have NaN values.

In the following example my result should be something like:

```
missing_dates = [('2018-10-10 20:00:00', '2018-10-10 22:00:00'),
('2018-10-11 02:00:00', '2018-10-11 03:00:00 ')]
```

If there 's a isolated NaN the value should be repeated in the tuple.

A dictionary example with a table for visualization.

```
   dicts = [
        {'datetime': '2018-10-10 18:00:00', 'variable1': 20, 'variable2': 30},
        {'datetime': '2018-10-10 19:00:00', 'variable1': 20, 'variable2': 30},
        {'datetime': '2018-10-10 19:00:00', 'variable1': 20, 'variable2': 30},
        {'datetime': '2018-10-10 19:00:00', 'variable1': 20, 'variable2': 30},
        {'datetime': '2018-10-10 20:00:00', 'variable1': np.nan, 'variable2': np.nan},
        {'datetime': '2018-10-10 21:00:00', 'variable1': np.nan, 'variable2': np.nan},
        {'datetime': '2018-10-10 22:00:00', 'variable1': np.nan, 'variable2': np.nan},
        {'datetime': '2018-10-10 23:00:00', 'variable1': 20, 'variable2': 30},
        {'datetime': '2018-10-10 23:00:00', 'variable1': 20, 'variable2': 30},
        {'datetime': '2018-10-11 00:00:00', 'variable1': 20, 'variable2': 30},
        {'datetime': '2018-10-11 01:00:00', 'variable1': np.nan, 'variable2': 30},
        {'datetime': '2018-10-11 02:00:00', 'variable1': np.nan, 'variable2': np.nan},
        {'datetime': '2018-10-11 03:00:00', 'variable1': np.nan, 'variable2': np.nan}]
```

Table representation:

```
----------------------+-----------+-----------+
|          datetime   | variable1 | variable2 |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+
| 2018-10-10 18:00:00 |      20.0 |     30.0  |
| 2018-10-10 19:00:00 |      20.0 |     30.0  | 
| 2018-10-10 19:00:00 |      20.0 |     30.0  |
| 2018-10-10 19:00:00 |      20.0 |     30.0  |
| 2018-10-10 20:00:00 |       NaN |     NaN   |
| 2018-10-10 21:00:00 |       NaN |     NaN   |
| 2018-10-10 22:00:00 |       NaN |     NaN   |
| 2018-10-10 23:00:00 |      20.0 |     30.0  |
| 2018-10-10 23:00:00 |      20.0 |     30.0  | 
| 2018-10-11 00:00:00 |      20.0 |     30.0  |
| 2018-10-11 01:00:00 |       NaN |     30.0  |
| 2018-10-11 02:00:00 |       NaN |     NaN   |
| 2018-10-11 03:00:00 |       NaN |     NaN   |
+---------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

What i did:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(example_dict)
s = dframe.set_index('datetime').isnull().all(axis=1)
df['new_col'] = s.values
dframe.datetime = pd.to_datetime(dframe.datetime)
new_df = dframe.loc[dframe['new_col'] == True]
new_df['delta'] = (new_df['datetime'] - new_df['datetime'].shift(1))
```

I got a nice dataframe with a delta but i'm a little lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#create boolean mask for not NaNs rows
mask = df.drop('datetime', axis=1).notnull().any(axis=1)
#create groups for missing rows with same values
df['g'] = mask.cumsum()

#aggregate first and last, convert to nested lists and map to tuples
L = list(map(tuple, df[~mask].groupby('g')['datetime'].agg(['first','last']).values.tolist()))
print (L)
[('2018-10-10 20:00:00', '2018-10-10 22:00:00'), 
 ('2018-10-11 02:00:00', '2018-10-11 03:00:00')]
```

Similar solution, only mask is inverted:

```
mask = df.drop('datetime', axis=1).isnull().all(axis=1)
df['g'] = (~mask).cumsum()

L = list(map(tuple, df[mask].groupby('g')['datetime'].agg(['first','last']).values.tolist()))
print (L)
[('2018-10-10 20:00:00', '2018-10-10 22:00:00'), 
 ('2018-10-11 02:00:00', '2018-10-11 03:00:00')]
```